# Error TS2339 'endpoint' dos not exist

Tags: cors, endpoint, environment

Hola Estoy haciendo un pequeño crud y al poner this.app.use(cors()); el la parte del servidor
me da un error this.myAppURL = enviroment.endpoint;

Basicamente estoy cambiando de ver los datos de un array declarado a ver los datos de una BBDD de AWS RDS. Las pruebas realizadas con postman me han funcionado bien. pero ha sido intentar ver el listado desde el frontEnd y no funcionar.

Soy nuevo en Angular y despues de leer mucho por internet no he conseguido ver como repararlo.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qLAAUb71jgGGIDzrfaDDXB6iCH9TS7kn?usp=sharing

Agradezo por anticipado las molestias que se va a tomar la comunidad en ayudarme,.

Mi codigo
empresa.service.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { Empresa } from '../interfaces/empresa';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class EmpresaService {

  
  private myAppUrl: string;
  private myApiUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.myAppUrl =  environment.endpoint ;
    this.myApiUrl = 'api/usuarios/'

  }

  getListEmpresas(): Observable<Empresa[]>{
    return this.http.get<Empresa[]>(`${this.myAppUrl}${this.myApiUrl}`);
  }
  
}
```

Codigo

enviroment.ts

```
export const environment = {
    production: false,
    endpoint :'http://localhost:3000/'
};
```

Comment: Buenas, Pedro, bienvenido al sitio. Quizás deberías echarle un ojo al [tour] para saber un poco más cómo funciona esto. Por favor, edita tu pregunta e incluye en ella el código relevante formateado.

Comment: Gracias he puesto capturas de pantalla

Comment: Nada. Falta cuál es el error que te da exactamente. Me temo que desconozco la sintaxis, ¿has revisado que todas las líneas que lo requieran terminen en ';'? ¿es válido el carácter '`'?

Comment: @Rubio en javascript los ; son opcionales. Aunque sí, es mejor si se usan. Y los backticks son para [interpolación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: Qué extraño. Prueba creando un tipo para la variable e indicaselo explícitamente.

Comment: @Mateo Gracias por las aclaraciones. :-)

Comment: Tienes que declarar las mismas variables en los 2 environments

Answer (score 0):

si alguien se vuelve a topar con este error , me sucedió igual en `angular 17`, lo que hice fue copiar la misma información del archivo `environment.ts` al `environment.development.ts`, esto teniendo en cuenta que en el servicio solo se importa el environment.ts, luego de eso ya no apareció de nuevo el error